# To Find Median value of a Data Frame in Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm working on a problem where I have imported a DB table into Apache Spark.

I have converted it into a DataFrame. Then I performed a RegisterTempTable so that I can use Hive Queries on it.

I'm able to perform other mathematical operations like,

```
sqlContext.sql("select avg(Amount) from Table1001").show
```

However I'm unable to find the median for a field called `Amount`. Is there any way to find the median on this DataFrame?

Kindly provide a suitable solution.

Comment: How do you find the `median`? Step 1 - sort; Step2 - pick the middle element.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DataFrameStatFunctions.approxQuantile` to calculate the median,

```
val medianArray = yourDataFrame.stat.approxQuantile("Amount", Array(0.5), 0)

val median = medianArray(0)
```

Note :: This operation is optimized for an approximate solution, rather than an accurate one. But we want an accurate solution hence supplied `relativeError = 0`, this operation can be expensive.

Comment: I received the error message : error: value approxQuantile is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameStatFunctions         Do we need to import any package ?

Comment: Spark Version ? It was added in Spark 2.0.

Answer (score 0):

To get the median, you can use the HIVE UDAF `percentile` if you have an `HiveContext` (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-Built-inAggregateFunctions(UDAF)) :

```
sqlContext.sql("select percentile(Amount, 0.5) from Table1001").show
```

If performance is an issue, you can also use `percentile_approx`